# Qt QDesktopServices::setUrlHandler not working (Mac)

Tags: qt, qml

I want to use web browser to open my app and pass some data.

I can using `urlApp://` open app by web browser, but how to pass data?

I tried `urlApp://test` there is not received to HandleURL::handleURL.

Platform

```
Qt 6.3.0
macOS 12.4
```

main.cpp register app url.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ....
    HandleURL *URLHandler = new HandleURL();
    QDesktopServices::setUrlHandler("urlApp", URLHandler, "handleURL");
    ....
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("URLHandler", URLHandler);
    ....
}
```

HadleUrl

```
#ifndef HANDLEURL_H
#define HANDLEURL_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDesktopServices>
#include <QUrl>
class HandleURL : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit HandleURL(){}

signals:
    void incomingURL(QString path);

public slots:
    void handleURL(const QUrl &url){
        emit incomingURL(url.toString());
    }
};

#endif // HANDLEURL_H
```

info.plist add CFBundleURLTypes

```
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>urlApp</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
          <string>urlApp</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </array>
```